# linq to entity query getting error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to amend a c# project. I am a vb.vet programmer so having a few issues as I am new to linq. I am trying to run a Linq to Entity query. I want to select the MapEast where town = town. I keep get an error `The specified cast from a materialized System.Decimal' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.`. I would like to put a max(1) in here too so it returns only the highest number.

```
var topEast = 0;
try
{
    topEast = this._uow.Addresses
            .Where(a => 
                a.Town.Trim().ToUpper() == town.Trim().ToUpper())
            .Select(m => m.MapEast).FirstOrDefault ();
    return -1;
}
catch
{
    return -1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer but a major issue with your code example: You should never call `toUpper()` or `toLower()` on a column as part of a LINQ to Entities query. It will produce a massive performance hit. You can use `.Where(a => a.Town.Equals(town, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

[`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) is used for implicitly typed local variable.  When you defined `var topEast = 0;`, `topEast` was implicitly assigned type `int`, and not decimal as per your query. You can fix it by explicitly defining `topEast` as decimal.

```
decimal topEast = 0;
```

> I would like to put a max(1) in here too so it returns only the
>   highest number.

Not really sure what you are trying to return, because you are returning `-1` from `try`  as well as catch block. If you are trying to return the `Max` value of `MapEast` field then you will need `Enumerable.Max`, otherwise `FirstOrDefault` would return the first item or null based on criteria.

Comment: Thanks @Habib. I still have the same error. I did try `decimal topEast = 0;` earlier when I want trying to figure out the error and I still got the cast error. I have just tried it again and I do still have the same error. The `return -1;` is only for testing purposes I eventually need to return an int after I have processed the map coordinates.

Comment: @Easty, what is the type of `MapEast` is it decimal or `Nullable<decimal>` / `decimal?` ?

Comment: Hhmmm that is maybe closer to my problem. I have looked in the addresses entity and I see `public int MapEast { get; set; }` yet the SQL DB is `Decimal(8,0)`. However I do have a linq query working correctly `this._uow.Addresses.Where(a => a.Street.Trim().ToUpper().Contains(street.Trim().ToUpper())).Where(a => a.PostCode.Trim().ToUpper() != "N\\A").GroupBy(m => new { m.Street, m.Town, m.PostCode }).Select(m => new Street() { MapEast = m.FirstOrDefault().MapEast, MapNorth = m.FirstOrDefault().MapNorth, Details = m.Key.Street + " " + m.Key.Town + " " + m.Key.PostCode }).AsEnumerable();`